# preventing opening of record on double click in dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, dynamics-365

I have set up a Queue for our Abstract entity. I am trying to prevent the double click opening of the record. I have set up a handler for the event, and call .stopPropagation() and .preventDefault() on the event object, and it continues to open up the window.

Not sure if I'm missing something obvious or what.. here's my code:

```
function attachDoubleClick() {
    var grid = document.getElementById("gridBodyTable");
    if (grid == null) {
        setTimeout(function () { attachDoubleClick(); }, 2000); //if the grid hasn’t loaded run this again
        return;
    }

    function handler(e) {
        var abstractId = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-crm-List-SelectedRow").item().getAttribute("oid").replace("}", "").replace("{","");
        XrmSvcToolkit.retrieve({
            entityName: "prod_abstract",
            id: abstractId,
            select: ["prod_abstractstatus"],
            async: false,
            successCallback: function (result) {
                if (result.prod_abstractstatus.Value != 108410000) {
                    alert("This abstract is already being worked on or is completed.");
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    console.log(e);
                    return;
                }
            },
            errorCallback: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
    grid.ondblclick = handler;
}
```

Comment: did you try "return false;" instead of return in success callback ?

Answer (score -1):

The issue was I needed to addEventListener with a 3rd parameter of true. (this is the useCapture parameter.) End code looked like this:

```
function attachDoubleClick() {
    var grid = document.getElementById("gridBodyTable");
    if (grid == null) {
        setTimeout(function () { attachDoubleClick(); }, 2000); //if the grid hasn’t loaded run this again
        return;
    }
    grid.addEventListener("dblclick", handler, true);
}


function handler(e) {
    console.log(e);
    var abstractId = document.getElementsByClassName("ms-crm-List-SelectedRow").item().getAttribute("oid").replace("}", "").replace("{", "");
    XrmSvcToolkit.retrieve({
        entityName: "prod_abstract",
        id: abstractId,
        select: ["prod_abstractstatus"],
        async: false,
        successCallback: function (result) {
            if (result.prod_abstractstatus.Value != 108410000) {
                alert("This abstract is already being worked on or is completed.");
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
        },
        errorCallback: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

}
```